# Problem with AMS packages

Tags: amsthm

I have a problem that occurs every time I use one of the AMS packages (regardless of the document class or template I use), for instance `amsmath` or `amsthm`. In the next line after the `\usepackage` command LaTeX identifies an error `File ended while scanning use of \@newenv.` It also shows several warnings which otherwise do not occur.

How do I get rid of this problem?

**Update**

After I cleared some lines in the document in order to provide an example, the problem disappeared. Then I added these lines back one by one compiling the document after each step. The problem never occurred. However I can make the error come back simply by the use of one of the templates that have these packages. This one I found at overleaf.com:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%%% Работа с русским языком
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}   %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{fontspec}      %% подготавливает загрузку шрифтов Open Type, True Type и др.
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}  %% свойства шрифтов по умолчанию
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman} %% задаёт основной шрифт документа
\setsansfont{Comic Sans MS}                    %% задаёт шрифт без засечек
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing


%%% Дополнительная работа с математикой
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} % AMS
\usepackage{icomma} % "Умная" запятая: $0,2$ --- число, $0, 2$ --- перечисление


\author{\LaTeX{} в Вышке}
\title{5.2.2. Русский язык в \LaTeX: Xe\LaTeX}
\date{\today}

\begin{document} % конец преамбулы, начало документа

    \maketitle

    \begin{abstract}
        Текст аннотации
    \end{abstract}

\end{document} % конец документа
```

**Update 2**

Sorry, the error didn't go away. I accidentally mixed up `amsmath` package with `amsthm`. **The error occurs only with the latter**.

**Update 3**

AMS packages info:

- amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
- amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
- amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
- amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
- amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
- amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2

Update 4

Complete log of MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

Log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.3.17)  27 MAY 2016 20:03
entering extended mode
**./document.tex
(document.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9n> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
(D:\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(D:\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
\thm@style=\toks14
\thm@bodyfont=\toks15
\thm@headfont=\toks16
\thm@notefont=\toks17
\thm@headpunct=\toks18
\thm@preskip=\skip43
\thm@postskip=\skip44
\thm@headsep=\skip45
\dth@everypar=\toks19
)
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \@newenv.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.3 \begin
          {document}
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

(document.aux)
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
 [1

{C:/Users/khizza/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (document.
aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 298 strings out of 493634
 3140 string characters out of 3147412
 52660 words of memory out of 3000000
 3765 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,17p,137b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<D:/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 12239 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Can you add one of those examples please? (A document, not just fragments, please!) Either you have a broken setup (i.e. your TeX distribution) or it's a strange misuse of `\usepackage{...}`

Comment: please provide a small compilable file so other people can test.  it would also be good to identify what versions of packages you're using; you can get that reported in the log with `\listfiles`.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: @David: I've tried your example and it works out of the box

Comment: Can you provide the information @barbarabeeton requested?

Comment: Sorry, this is the amsthm package information from the log file:
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
 amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
 amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
 amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
 amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2

Comment: since it was `amsthm`, not `amsmath` that triggered the problem (with the template), i've changed the tag.  comment on package list: `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so it's not necessary to load the latter separately. similarly with `mathtools`; that loads `amsmath` (and extends it).  but that shouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: Since the problem doesn't show on my machine, I can only suspect you have a corrupt copy of `amsthm.sty` on your system. Try reinstalling the `amscls` MiKTeX package. You might try looking at the file `D:\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty` and report the last 20 lines or so.

Comment: @egreg reinstalling the `amscls` MiKTeX package helped, thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because reinstallation of the `amscls` MiKTeX package solved the problem.